# why atmega32 recieves just the last 16 characters of string?

Tags: c, uart, atmega, codevisionavr

i use an atmega32 to communicate with SIM808. when module sends a string that contains more than 16 characters, atmega32 receives only the last 16 characters. it works fine with less characters. i use a 16*2 alphanumeric LCD to show the received data. i tried to extract part of the long string using strncpy().then i sent the extracted part to LCD, but LCD just shows nothing. i think  something is wrong with AVR ,not LCD. what can i do? i wrote c code simply by using codevision UART libraries.
here is the main code:

```
printf("AT+CGPSINF=2\r");
            scanf("%s",response);
            scanf("%s",response2);
            scanf("%s",response3);
            scanf("%s",response4);
            scanf("%s",response5);  
            lcd_clear(); 
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            lcd_puts(response);
            delay_ms(1000);
            lcd_clear(); 
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            lcd_puts(response2);
            delay_ms(1000);
            lcd_clear(); 
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            lcd_puts(response3); 
            delay_ms(1000);
            lcd_clear(); 
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            lcd_puts(response4);
            delay_ms(1000);
            lcd_clear(); 
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            lcd_puts(response5);
            delay_ms(1000);
            strncpy(response3,response3 + 18,26 - 18); 
            lcd_clear(); 
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            lcd_puts(response3); 
            delay_ms(1000);
```

response3[200] is for receiving long string.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: If the 16*2 LCD shows one line correctly when passed a string <= 16 characters, you should be looking at the data sheet  / function documentation to find out how to send the second line.

Comment: About the second line of the LCD. The code you posted (which is not an answer, it should be in the question) only ever has `lcd_gotoxy(0,0);` so how do you expect to show text on the second line?

Comment: in cvavr LCD library when string contains more than 16 chars, LCD automatically goes to second line and shows next characters of the string. it doesn't need anything else to go to next line. i am sure about this.

Comment: atmega and scanf :). When programing those micros avoid printf and scanf as a plaque. It will eat half of your flash memory.

Comment: add somewhere in the code as an experiment ad display the complete response3 string in chunks.     size_t len = strlen(response3);
    size_t pos = 0;
    
    while(len)
    {
        char tmp[17];
        
        lcd_clear(); 
        lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
        strncpy(tmp, response3 + pos, len >= 16 ? 16 : len);
        len -= len >= 16 ? 16 : len;
        pos += len >= 16 ? 16 : len;
        tmp[16] = 0
        lcd_puts(tmp); 
        delay_ms(1000);
    }